# Count total of each activity type - oracle - sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 3 activity types and need to display how many people have taken part in each event. So for example I need the query to display:

- activity type ----------- total
- Snowboarding   ---------        9
- Skiing          -------------------       7
- Sledging   ----------------            5

So far I have written the following query:

```
SELECT type_of_activity, COUNT (DISTINCT individual_id) 
FROM activities, events, book_activity
WHERE activities.activity_code = events.activity_code 
      AND events.event_id = book_activity.event_id;
```

This is obviously wrong and comes up with the error "`not a single group function`"

What I need it to do is count each unique instances of individual ID where type - skiing for each type. I have looked at many resources but cannot find any examples or help

Comment: Could you include your database schema.

Comment: What is the error number you get?  Is it ORA-00979?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.type_of_activity, COUNT(ba.individual_id)
FROM BOOK_ACTIVITY ba
JOIN EVENTS e
  ON e.event_id = ba.event_id
JOIN ACTIVITIES a
  ON a.activity_code = e.activity_code
GROUP BY a.type_of_activity;
```

Comment: Thank you! Being trying to do this for hours

Comment: I noticed that I did leave out one part. Are `INDIVUDUALS` able to do the same `EVENT` multiple times? Or is the combination of `event_id`, `individual_id` in the `BOOK_ACTIVITY` table unique?

Comment: What you've done has helped me do it correctly so that was all I needed, thanks again